# Prolog query fails

Tags: recursion, prolog, sum

This is supposed to calculate the sum of two lists. The lists can be of different size.

```
sum([],[],[]).
sum(A,[],A).
sum([],B,B).
sum([A|Int1],[B|Int2],[C|Int3]) :-
  (
    C =:= A + B
  ;
    ((C =:= A), B = [])
  ;
    ((C =:= B), A = [])
  ),
  sum(Int1,Int2,Int3).
```

It seems to work correctly, except when trying to find the sum of two lists. Then it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I don't see why. There's a recursive and a basis step, what exactly is not yet instantiated and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] While your disjunctions in the last clause are -- to some extent -- conceptually correct, Prolog considers these disjunctions in sequence. So it first considers `C =:= A + B`. But either `A` or `B` can be the empty list! This is what causes the error you reported, since the empty list is not allowed to occur in a numeric operation.

[2] You need to use `C is A + b` (assignment) i.o. `C =:= A + B` (numeric equivalence).

[3] If you say `[A|Int1]` and then `A = []`, then this means that `[A|Int1]` is not (only) a list of integers (as you claim it is) but (also) a list of lists! You probably intend to check whether the first or the second list is empty, not whether either contains the empty list.

Staying close to your original program, I would suggest to reorder and change things in the following way:

```
sumOf([], [], []):- !.
sumOf([], [B|Bs], [C|Cs]):- !,
  C is B,
  sumOf([], Bs, Cs).
sumOf([A|As], [], [C|Cs]):- !,
  C is A,
  sumOf(As, [], Cs).
sumOf([A|As], [B|Bs], [C|Cs]):-
  C is A + B,
  sumOf(As, Bs, Cs).
```

For example:

```
?- sumOf([1,2,3], [1,-90], X).
X = [2, -88, 3]
```

Notice my use of the cut (symbol `!`) in the above. This makes sure that the same answer is not given multiple times or -- more technically -- that no *choicepoints* are kept (and is called *determinism*).

Comment: @user3614293 Indeed, for numeric assignments which involves no numeric operation you can use unification. And the first clause is indeed not needed since it is covered by the second (and third) clause. My code sample was intended to be quite close to your original program, but the version you give in the comment indeed contains less redundancy. I would add a cut in the first clauses though, for determinism.

Answer (score 1):

You should read a tutorial or a book. Anyway, this is how you add two things to each other:

```
Result is A + B
```

This is how you could add all elements of one list:

```
sum([], 0). % because the sum of nothing is zero
sum([X|Xs], Sum) :-
    sum(Xs, Sum0),
    Sum is X + Sum0.
```

And this is how you could add the sums of a list of lists:

```
sums([], 0).
sums([L|Ls], Sums) :-
    sums(Ls, Sums0),
    sum(L, S),
    Sums is Sums0 + S.
```

Comment: I like your solution, but the task was to use only one predicate sum.